# Selenium FireFoxDriver Profile changing after loading firefox?

Tags: java, image, selenium, blocking, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default");//using firefox default profile
ffprofile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2); // this make ff to block web page images
WebDriver ff = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);    // executing firefox with specified profile 
ff.navigate().to("www.google.com");             // loading web page  



//codes for changing image blocking ???????????
```

How can I change the image blocking after loading some web pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to modify preferences in flight via dev toolbar CLI but it may introduce higher overhead than loading images.
Here is Python example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains, Keys

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get('http//<URL>')

ac = ActionChains(ff)
# SHIFT+F2 opens dev toolbar
ac.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.F2).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
# command to disable images
ac.send_keys('pref set permissions.default.image 2').perform()
ac.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
# command to disable flash
ac.send_keys('pref set plugin.state.flash 0').perform()
ac.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
# disable dev toolbar
ac.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.F2).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
ac.key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.F2).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
# reload the page to confirm there are no images or flash
ff.refresh()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the dev toolbar CLI does not work for me (since the key combination does not open the CLI) here is how I managed to change profile settings of a running firefox instance:

```
        IWebDriver driver = //your instance
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("about:config");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("warningButton")).Click();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        js.ExecuteScript("window.Services.prefs.setIntPref('permissions.default.image', " + 2 + ")");
```

It's C# but the conversion in Java should not be too hard. 
The idea is that the about:config tab declares a lot of Javascript object allowing to change the profile settings, so we just have to go on that page and to execute some JS code.

Answer (score -1):

Run the firefox from command line firefox.exe -p

After that create a new profile, set the neccessery settings and always call this profile.

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("profileName");
```

Comment: I can load any firefox profile successfully. But I want to change the profile setting after firefox load. Users can change any profile setting by input "about:config" in the ff address bar. I want to change it programmatically.

Comment: That's not possible. The profile is created before creating Firefox instance and it can't be changed.

Comment: Yes. That is not possible to change "profile" after firefox load but  i want to change  "PROFILE SETTING". please try to change the profile by input "about:config" in the address bar. Then you can change any preferences such as "permission.default.images" to block images.

Comment: Hi khostro, have you succeeded with programmatically updating profile settings _after_ firefox loaded?